# Why doesnt this regexp work for this html?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```html
<div class="_1zGQT _2ugFP message-in">
    <div class="-N6Gq">
        <div class="copyable-text" data-pre-plain-text="[18:09, 3.6.2019] Лера сестра: ">
            <div class="_12pGw">
                <div class="_3X58t selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text">
                    <span class="_2ZDCk">
                        <img crossorigin="anonymous" src="URL" alt="" draggable="false" class="_298rb _2FANH selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text" data-plain-text="" style="visibility: visible;">
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ive try to get  with this code:

```py
soup.find('div', class_=re.compile('^selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text'))
```

All i got: None.
The problem is that part of the class (_3X58t ) is changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be likely due to using `^` anchor, which we could modify to:

```
soup.find('div', class_=re.compile('selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text'))
```

or we might try this expression for the divs:

```
(.+?selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/utMIAi/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I would first see if a single class, from the compound class list, could be used e.g.

```
soup.select_one('.selectable-text')
```

Else combine classes

```
soup.select_one('[class$="selectable-text invisible-space copyable-text"]')
```

Rather than resorting to regex.